# How to get number of rows with Advantage PHP Extension?

Tags: php, advantage-database-server

How can I get the number of rows from a SELECT statement result set using the Advantage Database PHP Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own function that works similar to mysql_num_rows:

```
function my_num_rows($result) {
    ob_start(); // begin disable output from ads_result_all
    (int)$number = ads_result_all($result);
    ob_end_clean(); //close and clean the output buffer
    ads_fetch_row($r1, 0); // reset the result set pointer to the beginning
    if ($number >= 0){
         return $number;
    } else {
         return FALSE;
    }
}
```

It could also be rewritten to count the rows using ads_fetch_row but this was easier for what I needed. With large result sets there could be slower performance using ads_result_all.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to count the rows as they are fetched.  (you can see this KB item [070618-1888](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=070618-1888)) or you can execute a second query with the COUNT() scalar (suggest excluding order by if possible)

Here is an example of counting as you go:

```
$rStmt = ads_do ($rConn, "select id, name from table1");
$RowCount = 0;
while (ads_fetch_row($rStmt))
{
   $id = ads_result ($rStmt, "id");
   $name = ads_result($rStmt, "name");
   echo $id . "\t" . $name . "\n";
   $RowCount++;
}
echo "RowCount:" . $RowCount . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried doing it that way but the problem I was having was that after counting the rows, the result pointer ends up at the end of the result set and needs to be reset. I ended up using the method I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Version 12 as far as I know you have the function ads_num_rows(). Please see in official documentation for further usage.